# How to add a Listener programatically for Servlets?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-3.0

In Servlet 3.0 there is a way to add listeners programatically in ServletContextListener's contextInitialized() method. Servlets and Filters can be added programatically as below (**please correct the below code if I am wrong**)

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {

        ServletContext sc = sce.getServletContext();

        // Register Servlet
        ServletRegistration sr = sc.addServlet("DynamicServlet",
            "com.sample.DynamicServlet");
        sr.setInitParameter("servletInitName", "servletInitValue");
        sr.addMapping("/dynamic");

// Register Filter
FilterRegistration fr = sc.addFilter("DynamicFilter","com.sample.TestFilter");
fr.setInitParameter("filterInitName", "filterInitValue");
fr.addMappingForServletNames(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST),
                                     true, "DynamicServlet");
    }
```

Likewise, I was hoping if anyone could share an example of adding a Listener programatically as I don't know how to do it.

Also is it possible to add `ServletContextListener` itself programatically? If yes, then where should I add it?. As all the Servlets, Listeners, Filter's and their instantiation is done from `contextInitialized()` method. So if I have to instantiate it programatically where should I declare it?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `ServletContextListener` programmatically since Servlet 3.0, by calling `ServletContext.addListener(Class<? extends EventListener>)`.

However this can only be done from `ServletContainerInitializer.onStartup` which is run before any `ServletContextListeners` are called.

---

The Javadoc of `ServletContext.addListener(Class<? extends EventListener>)` reads:

> Adds a listener of the given class type to this ServletContext.
>   The given listenerClass must implement one or more of the following
>   interfaces:
>
> ```
> ServletContextAttributeListener
> ServletRequestListener
> ServletRequestAttributeListener
> HttpSessionAttributeListener
> HttpSessionIdListener
> HttpSessionListener
> ```
>
> If this ServletContext was passed to
>   `ServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(...)`, then the given listenerClass may also
>   implement `ServletContextListener`, in addition to the interfaces listed
>   above.